# Conditionally composing a selector using reselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

```
export const mySelector = createSelector(
    [selectorA, selectorB], // but I want selectorB or selectorC to be chosen here using logic
    (foo, bar) => {
        // ...
    }
);
```

I want to conditionally use `selectorB` or `selectorC` when creating this selector based on the state in the store (i.e. the value returned by another selector).

How can I do this?

Comment: Have not tried reselect. What issue are you having using logic to determine the value?

Comment: @Ben Let me know, if you got the idea from my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to point out that the approach suggested in the accepted answer would evaluate both **selectorB** and **selectorC** on each **selectorCorB** call. Which is not probably the desired behaviour.

An actual conditional call might be implemented like this:

```
export const selectorCorB = createSelector(
    selectorStateX
    (...arguments) => arguments,
    (x, arguments) => x ? selectorB(...arguments) : selectorC(...arguments)
);
```

Comment: `(...arguments) => arguments,` this would call the selector on any state change

Answer (score 3):

then make a selectorCorB composing selectorB, selectorC , selectorX

selectorX is the selector of that variable x from store which decides either selectorB or selectorC

```
const selectorCorB = createSelector(
  selectorB,
  selectorC,
  selectorStateX,
  (b, c, x) => x? b: c
) 

mySelector = createSelector(
    [selectorA, selectorCorB], // will be A AND B OR C depending on x
    (foo, cOrb) => {
        // ...
    }
);
```